# Declaring array of the same type declared in a service TypeScript file?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array in a typescript service file. How do i declare an array in my component class of the type of the array in my service class.
Here is my array declaration in the service typescript file.

```
export class ChannelsService {
 channels= [
    {
      pickCode: '780',
      cbsCode: 'AE',
      channel: 'A&E',
      logo: '/assets/A&E.png',
      compChannel: {
        compChannelCbsCode: '',
        compChannelName: '',
        compChannelLogo: ''
      }
    },
    {
      pickCode: '911',
      cbsCode: 'ABCSPK',
      channel: 'ABC Spark',
      logo: '/assets/ABC Spark.jpg',
      compChannel: {
        compChannelCbsCode: '',
        compChannelName: '',
        compChannelLogo: ''
      }
    },
```

I am looking to declare an array of the same channels array in my service typescript file in my component class.
This is the way I did it now, it doesn't work

```
import { ChannelsService } from './channels.service';
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  draggedChannel: Array<this.channelsService.channels>[];
  constructor(private pickGroupService: PickGroupService, private channelsService: ChannelsService) {}
```

Comment: `draggedChannel: Array<this.channelsService.channels>[];` what this line infers ?? can you elaborate

Comment: Why dont you create a model ChannelModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`No`** that won't work, you can create a new class/interface as follows and use that type

I have used  **[`json2ts`](http://json2ts.com/)** here, you can change according to your need,

```
export interface CompChannel {
        compChannelCbsCode: string;
        compChannelName: string;
        compChannelLogo: string;
    }

    export interface RootObject {
        pickCode: string;
        cbsCode: string;
        channel: string;
        logo: string;
        compChannel: CompChannel;
    }
```

Comment: @Aravind, I was not sure what I was doing, totally new to angular and typescript, was just trying out different ways.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Hey Sajeetharan, I was trying to make it work the way you suggested, but I was having trouble adding data. Could you post an example of that as well.

Comment: what do you mean by adding data?

Comment: declaring the model with data on my service typescript file.

Comment: just import inside the component  draggedChannel: Array<RootObject >[];

Comment: Thanks to all for the prompt responses

Answer (score 0):

While declaring an interface an using it in the array declaration is the better approach, you can get the type of the array like this:

```
// Just a dummy var so we can access instance properties
declare var _dummy : ChannelsService; 
// we use typeof to get the type of the array.
type ArrayType = typeof _dummy.channels;
let array : ArrayType; // Use the array type like any other
```